# post a pic in a database in php

Tags: php, post, image

I am trying to test how to upload a pic on my wamp database but I have a of "Undefined index:Pic" error. Could you please help me? Thank you!

Here is the code of my formulaire:

```
  <form action="PicPost.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
   Formulaire d'envoi de fichier :<br />
   <input type="file" name="Pic" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Post the pic" />
    </p>
    </form>
```

And here is the file that should treat it:

```
    <?php
    try
    {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO picdb (Picture)
    VALUES(?)');
    $req->execute(array($_POST['Pic']));
    ?>
```

Comment: Please google 'file upload php' that should give you a good starting point.

Comment: `<input type="file">` Uses the superglobal `$_FILES`

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/features.file-upload - explains how it basically works with the forms and the file upload fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt This To Your Environment

**Select Pic To Upload:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php" method="post" name="changer">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
```

**insert.php**

```
  if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

              // Temporary file name stored on the server
              $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

              // Read the file 
              $fp     = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
              $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
              $data = addslashes($data);
              fclose($fp);


              // Create the query and insert
              // into our database.
             $Insert = $bdd->query("insert into picdb (ID, Pic) VALUES ('', $data)");

              // Print results
              print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

    }
    else {
       print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }
```

Here you have a file uploader.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying with a jpeg of just 67 ko, but I always have the following error message: "No image selected/uploaded". Any idea? Are you sure about the "read the file" section? It seems  that $data is not really prepared.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the file is in file $_FILES['Pic']['tmp_name']. See this page for more info about how to handle file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

You should also consider storing just the file name in the database and keep the actual images in normal files.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I need a database to be able later to have pics with tags and related to users on my website.